# AVPlayer Audio Output

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, avcapturesession

Through `AVCaptureSession` I record a video and then immediately play it back via an `AVPlayer` once recording has stopped.

My problem is that the audio from the video sometimes plays out of the ear speaker at a really low volume and other times plays out of the bottom speaker.

How can I default the audio to output to the bottom speaker?

I've looked at other related posts with instances of the below code, which I tried, but to no avail..Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

do {
    try session.setCategory(.playAndRecord)
    try session.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSession.PortOverride.none)
    try session.setActive(true)
} catch {
    print ("error")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're explicitly turning that off here:

```
try session.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSession.PortOverride.none)
```

If you want to prefer the speaker, you'd use:

```
try session.overrideOutputAudioPort(.speaker)
```

AVAudioSession is very complicated, and many parts of it are not intuitive. Do not copy code you find on the internet without reading the docs on each command. The docs are pretty good, but you have to read them.

That said, rather than doing this, I'd probably switch your category and options when you switch to playback. You can do that at any time:

```
try session.setCategory(.playback, options: [.defaultToSpeaker])
```

It is generally best to keep your category aligned what you're doing. If you set `.playback` here as the category, you may not even need `.defaultToSpeaker`, depending on what precisely you're trying to achieve.

Be certain to read all the relevant docs on `.defaultToSpeaker`, `setCategory`, `overrideOutputAudioPort`, etc. Don't just copy my suggestions. These settings have many subtle (and documented) interactions, you need to configure it based on your actual use case, not just copy something that "seems to work." You may be very surprised at what happens when the user switches to Bluetooth, or plugs headphones, or switches to CarPlay.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the audio output device for a given AVPlayer instance by setting the instance property 'audioOutputDeviceUniqueID' to the UniqueID of the desired device.

I can confirm that this works as expected in MacOS 10.11.6, using Key-Value coding ( setValue:forKey:)

### Apple's doc on this:

Instance Property
audioOutputDeviceUniqueID
Specifies the unique ID of the Core Audio output device used to play audio.

Declaration
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *audioOutputDeviceUniqueID;
Discussion
The default value of this property is nil, indicating that the default audio output device is used. Otherwise the value of this property is a string containing the unique ID of the Core Audio output device to be used for audio output.

Core Audio's kAudioDevicePropertyDeviceUID is a suitable source of audio output device unique IDs.

---